# "warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration" in struct

Tags: c, struct, error-handling, compiler-errors, linked-list

```
typedef struct item {
    char *text;
    int count;
    struct item *next;
};
```

So I have this struct with nodes defined as above, but Im getting the error below and Im not able to figure out whats wrong.

> warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
>    };

Comment: You forgot to give it a name: `typedef struct item {
    char *text;
    int count;
    struct item *next;
} tralalala;`

Comment: I thought using typedef in structs working with pointers was not advisable? Should I use typedef even if I will have no use for it?

Comment: Generally, you don't need typedefs. Hiding pointers behind a typedef is extra confusing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try like that :

```
typedef struct item {
  char *text;
  int count;
  struct item *next;
}item;
```

Comment: Is `struct item *next;` the same as declaring the pointer out of the struct braces ?

Answer (score 11):

`typedef` is used to create a shorthand notation for an existing type in C. It is similar to `#define` but unlike it, `typedef` is interpreted by the compiler and offers more advanced capabilities than the preprocessor.

With its simplest form, `typedef` is given as

```
typedef existing_type new_type;
```

for instance,

```
typedef unsigned long UnsignedLong;
```

For example, if you trace the definition of `size_t` back to its root, you will see that

```
/* sys/x86/include/_types.h in FreeBSD */
/* this is machine dependent */
#ifdef  __LP64__
typedef unsigned long       __uint64_t;
#else
__extension__
typedef unsigned long long  __uint64_t;
#endif
...
...
typedef __uint64_t  __size_t;
```

and then

```
/* stddef.h */
typedef __size_t    size_t;
```

which actually means, `size_t` is an alias for `unsigned long long`,depending on the 64-bit modal (LP64, ILP64, LLP64) your machines has.

For your question, you attempt to define a new type but do not name it. Don't let the `struct item {..}` definition confuse you, it is just a type you are declaring. If you replace the whole `struct item {...}` with a basic type, say with an `int`, and rewrite your `typedef`, you would end up something like this

```
typedef int; /* new type name is missing */
```

the correct form should be

```
typedef struct item {...} Item;
```

See the examples below for different structure definitions

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* a new type, namely Item, is defined here */
typedef struct item_t {
  char *text;
  int count;
  struct item_t *next; /* you canot use Item here! */
} Item;

/* a structure definition below */
struct item {
  char *text;
  int count;
  struct item *next;
};

/* an anonymous struct
* However, you cannot self-refence here 
*/
struct {
  int i;
  char c;
} anon;

int main(void) {
  /* a pointer to an instance of struct item */
  struct item *pi;

  /* Shorthand for struct item_t *iI */
  Item *iI;

  /* anonymoous structure */
  anon.i = 9;
  anon.c = 'x';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The typedef is useless because you didn't give it a name. You cannot use the typedef in any way. That's why you get a warning, because the typedef is useless.

Answer (score 2):

The struct is actually still usable without the warning if you remove the typedef keyword like this:

```
struct item {
    char *text;
    int count;
    struct item *next;
};
```

You just need to include the 'struct' keyword in the variable declaration. i.e.

```
struct item head;
```

as other have pointed out if you include the name at the end of the struct definition then you can use it as the typedef and you get rid of the warning even without the struct keyword but this makes the first instance of 'item' superfluous i.e.

```
typedef struct {
    char *text;
    int count;
    struct item *next;
} item;

item head;
```

will also get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

This is an oldie, but stumbled here because I had the same linker error.

I made the foolish mistake of naming a file with an extension .c,  and should have been .cpp - created the SAME error - so watch out!

Renamed the file to have a .cpp extension, and the problem magically went away.

Took a while to figure that out, so happy to share my experience.