# Error in my data structure [STACK]

Tags: c, list, data-structures

[image]My code is displaying two errors. As I'm learning, I've tried several ways to fix it. Please, can anyone help me ?

I need to insert a number and a string in my stack. But you're making a mistake in my structure.

As I'm still a beginner, I'm having trouble seeing in general, but I think the way is right, maybe it's a syntax error.

> Ligacacao *topo - [Error] unknown type name 'Ligacacao'
>
> Ligacacao *pnovo = (Ligacacao*)malloc(sizeof(Ligacacao)); - [Error] 'Ligacacao' undeclared (first use in this function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX 5

typedef struct Ligacacao {
    char hora[MAX];
    int numero;
    struct Ligacacao *prox;
};

char hora[MAX];
int numero;
Ligacacao *topo; //ERRRRRRO


void dados_ligacao() {
    printf("\nEntre com a hora da chamada: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(hora, MAX, stdin);
    printf("Entre com o numero do telefone: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &numero);
}
void push_ligacao() {

    dados_ligacao();
    Ligacacao *pnovo = (Ligacacao*)malloc(sizeof(Ligacacao));//ERRRRRRO
    strcpy(pnovo->hora, hora);
    pnovo->numero = numero;
    pnovo->prox = NULL;
    if (topo == NULL)//se a pilha estiver vazia
        topo = pnovo; //topo recebe o novo elemento
    else {
        pnovo->prox = topo;
        topo = pnovo;
    }
}

void pop_ligacao() {
    Ligacacao *aux;
    if (topo == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nErro, Sem ligacoes.\n\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        aux = topo;
        topo = topo->prox;
        free(aux);
    }
}

void listar_ligacao() {
    Ligacacao *aux;
    aux = topo;
    while (aux != NULL) {
        printf("\t\t\tDados Ligacao\n\n");
        printf("Numero: %d", aux->numero);
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
}

int main() {
    char op;
    topo = NULL;
    do {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t\Ligacoes");
        printf("\n\n(E)mpilhar Ligacacao\n");
        printf("(L)istar Estoque Ligacacaos\n");
        printf("(D)esempilhar Ligacacao\n");
        printf("(S)air do Programa\n\n");
        printf("Digite a opcao: ");
        op = toupper(getche());
        switch (op) {
        case'E': push_ligacao();
            break;
        case'L': listar_ligacao();
            break;
        case'D': pop_ligacao();
            break;
        case'S': exit(0);
        default: printf("\n\nOpcao invalida, digite novamente.\n\n");
        }
        system("PAUSE");
    } while (op != 'S');
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."_

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: moooeeeep thank you. I'll be more specific.

Comment: If you are getting errors and want help with them, you should include what the errors are.

Comment: Also warnings can be revealing. Make a habit to compile with all warnings enabled by default. Most of the time the most relevant error will be found _before_ the point where the first error/warning is triggered...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration" in struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229811/warning-useless-storage-class-specifier-in-empty-declaration-in-struct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error 1 (line 21):**

```
typedef struct Ligacacao {
    char hora[MAX];
    int numero;
    struct Ligacacao *prox;
};
```

Should be:

```
typedef struct {
    char hora[MAX];
    int numero;
    struct Ligacacao *prox;
}Ligacacao;
```

**Error 2 (line 39):**

```
pnovo->prox = topo;
```

should probably be:

```
pnovo->prox = topo->prox;
```

**Error 3 (line 52):**

```
topo = topo->prox;
```

Is wrong but can't be assigned to itself either:

```
topo->prox= topo->prox;
```

**Error 4 (line 63):**

```
aux = aux->prox;
```

Same here.

**Error 5 (line 72):**

```
printf("\t\t\Ligacoes");
```

Should either be:

```
printf("\t\t\tLigacoes");
```

or:

```
printf("\t\tLigacoes");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are typdeffing your struct incorrectly.  Maybe try this:

```
typedef struct Ligacacao {
    char hora[MAX];
    int numero;
    struct Ligacacao *prox;
} Ligacacao;
```

Also, you might find a problem with this: `printf("\t\t\Ligacoes");`
That last backslash probably shouldn't be there, or perhaps you meant to put another 't' afterwards for another tab character.

Comment: Ty my brother. Correct

Comment: This is the better answer because the struct 'tagname' will be needed by 'most' debuggers to be able to display the individual fields of the struct